# Symfony Cache problems

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony and Doctrine (I am not expert) I was creating a code to work with my Mysql database

```
/**
* TcCourse
*
* @ORM\Table(name="tc_course")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class TcCourse
{

 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column( type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
  private $id;
```

However when I tried to run the source code using a Controller I was obtaining :

```
Property AppBundle\Entity\TcCourse::$userid does not exist
```

$userid was my previous property insted of $id 
I stop the server and start the server n-times because I was pretty sure that the code was ok

```
php app/console server:start
php app/console server:stop
```

always I got the same error

I find a solution using this (Because the code was ok)

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

What are your recomendations about  server cache in order to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: Use `dev` env in your development environment (not `prod` one), that was described well in symfony docs.

Comment: I have a doubt Mateus, when I start the server using  `php app/console server:start` is in dev environement ritgh? source: [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html)